# Result of HashMap .get() call references local variable used for lookup

Tags: rust, reference, hashmap

I'm attempting to perform multiple lookups into a HashMap. In the program's main loop, my method works just fine. However, once I try to move the logic into a function to hide some messy implementation details (case sensitivity of the HashMap keys), I get an error from the compiler stating: `returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`, aimed at `(x86_instruction, x86_64_instruction)`.
The code as in the program's main loop:

```rust
let raised_word = word.to_uppercase();
let x86_instruction =
    names_to_instructions.get(&(Arch::X86, &*word)).map_or_else(
        || {
            names_to_instructions
                .get(&(Arch::X86, &raised_word))
        },
        |instr| Some(instr),
    );
let x86_64_instruction =
    names_to_instructions.get(&(Arch::X86_64, &*word)).map_or_else(
        || {
            names_to_instructions
                .get(&(Arch::X86_64, &raised_word))
        },
        |instr| Some(instr),
   );
```

Attempting to move into a function:

```rust
pub fn search_for_instr<'a>(
    word: &'a str, 
    map: &'a NameToInstructionMap<'a>
) -> (Option<&'a&'a Instruction>, Option<&'a&'a Instruction>) {
    let raised_word = word.to_uppercase();

    let x86_instruction =
    map.get(&(Arch::X86, &*word)).map_or_else(
        || {
            map
                .get(&(Arch::X86, &raised_word))
        },
        |instr| Some(instr),
    );
    let x86_64_instruction =
    map.get(&(Arch::X86_64, &*word)).map_or_else(
        || {
            map
                .get(&(Arch::X86_64, &raised_word))
        },
        |instr| Some(instr),
   );

    (x86_instruction, x86_64_instruction)
}
```

I don't understand why a result of a HashMap lookup is referencing data used for its lookup via `.get()`. There are likely ways to get around this issue with some carefully placed `.clone()`'s, but I'd prefer a cleaner solution if possible. I also realize that I could pass in `raised_word` as a String argument rather than create it as a local variable, but this feels rather leaky to me abstraction-wise.

Comment: Please share the exact types of your variables and full compiler error.

Comment: However at the first glance `&'a&'a Instruction` is probably source of your problem. Such double lifetimes rarely (if ever) make sense.

Comment: As well as `&'a NameToInstructionMap<'a>`. Can you show type definition of `NameToInstructionMap`? What it borrows, and why for lifetime `'a`?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze the same lifetime twice is only a problem with mutable references, with shared ones the compiler is allowed to apropriately shorten them. The real problem is trying to return a reference to `raised_word` which OP just can't do.

Comment: @cafce25 OP is not trying to return a reference to `raised_word` though, this seems like [80385](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80389): the signature of `HashMap::get` uses the same (elided) lifetime for `self` and `key`, so the compiler considers that the value depends on the lifetime of the key, even though there is no relation once the value has been fetched.

Comment: Ah, missed the `get` in `map_or_else` at first glance. OP you could use `or_else` instead to not have to pass the useless `|x| Some(x)` closure.

Comment: Absolutely, the code is overly complex, but sadly that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The exact type of map is defined in another file via `pub type NameToInstructionMap<'a> = HashMap<(Arch, &'a str), &'a Instruction>`.  Arch is a 2-variant enum and Instruction is a struct. I can post the full definition of it if that would be helpful. I'll post the full compiler error in my next comment due to character limitations.

Comment: Compiler error (an identical error is repeated for the `x86_instruction` assignment as well.
`error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `raised_word`
  --> src/lsp.rs:73:5
   |
70 |         None => map.get(&(Arch::X86_64, &raised_word)),
   |                                         ------------ `raised_word` is borrowed here
...
73 |     (x86_instruction, x86_64_instruction)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515'.`

Comment: @cafce25 Great catch, thank you! I've swapped the code to use `or_else` instead of `map_or_else`. Unfortunately the error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like [Issue 80389 "Lifetime of input (key) to HashMap::get() gets entanged w/ that of its output (value)"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80389): the signature of `HashMap::get` is

```
fn get<Q>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
```

so `&V` takes the lifetime of `&self` *and `&Q`*, aka it is tied to the lifetime of the key, even though the key is only needed during retrieval and irrelevant thereafter. So sadly I don't think there's a fix, except cloning the result of `get`.

Do note that your code is way more complicated than necessary, the `map_` of `map_or_else` is not useful, and neither is the double reference in the result. Also the lifetime of the map and that of its values should very much not be the same.

Comment: I agree the code was messy/ over complex. I swapped from `map_or_else` to `or_else` and added a separate lifetime ``'b`` for the results now such that `'a: 'b`. While I'd rather avoid the extra allocations, I've added `.cloned()` calls on all the results to get things down to a single reference. Thanks so much for helping to clear things up!